# How to check where my disk-space goes in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: storage, ubuntu-10.04, diskspace

How can i check the size of multiple (all) folders to see where most of my diskspace goes?
Is there a way to know why my diskspace is low without knowing where most storage is held?

To be short: I want to know where my diskspace is located, how can i do that.
This can be a GUI application of commandline commands.. Hope somebody can help.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is du

To get a graphical overview, install xdu

```
apt-get install xdu
```

and use:

```
du -k <directory> | xdu
```

That is, to view your entire file system

```
du -k / | xdu
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, you could use the `du` utility (disk usage).

Or you could try invoking ls with the recursive option, a la `ls -lR`.

These are both commandline.

There is also a graphical disk usage analyzer, (or maybe more than one), which you should be able to locate from the commandline.